# Using Vue transition groups to animate column change in CSS grid

Tags: css, vue.js, css-animations, css-grid

I have a grid of cards (using a `<ul>` and CSS-Grid) which I render in Vue with a `v-for` loop. The grid is animated with Vue transitions, so that when I delete a card it fades out nicely and all the other cards move into place smoothly (for the exact setup see below). So far so good.

Now to the actual question: The grid is setup in such a way that the number of columns depends on the width of the grid (again, see below), so that a wider window will give more columns.

Now to the actual question:
When I resize the windows, this triggers a change in the number of columns, so my cards move around. However, this doesn't seem to trigger the Vue list-animation mechanism. The cards just jump to their new position without animating.

Is there any way to make them animate smoothly? I would be open to use flexbox instead, even though a grid is actually the cleaner solution.

---

For reference, this is the setup so far:

I have a grid of cards that I set up like so:

```
.card-grid {
  position: relative;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 15rem);
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;

  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

The actual grid is (as you can imaginge) a `ul` element with a bunch of `li` elements in it, but I don't think it should really matter what the tags are. The result is a grid of cards, with columns that are 15 rem wide. Depending on the width of the grid I get a different number of columns. This is exactly how I want it to be: a wider screen gives you more columns, a narrower screen gives fewer columns.

I animate the entries in this list with a transition group:

```
<transition-group
  name="card-grid"
  tag="ul"
  class="card-grid"
  @before-leave="cardGridBeforeLeave"
>
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" class="card-grid__item">
    <card :item="item" />
  </li>
</transition-group>
```

The corresponding transition classes:

```
.card-grid-leave-active {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in, opacity 0.2s ease;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.card-grid-move {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

When I delete a card I do a fade-shrink animation and using some JavaScript in the `cardGridBeforeLeave` hook I assign `position: absolute` and the corresponding `top` and `left` values, so that the other elements move into place while the deleted card fades out.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: No, I gave up. I convinced myself that it's better like this anyways, since the reshuffle from on window resize would be a lot of movement at once and would be disorienting the user or something...